# How to exportand play video synchronously

Tags: ios

I have use AVAssetExportSession to export video, which is slow.In order to play the exported video synchronously.
I find AVAssetResourceLoader can custom the AVPlayItem’s load process.Is it possible to read the unfinished exported video file to fill AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest for AVPlayer?
Thanks!